# Embedded Tomcat to serve JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to embed Tomcat in an application to serve static contents and JSPs. My code is the following:

```
        tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setBaseDir(plugin.getDataFolder().getAbsolutePath());
        tomcat.setPort(80);

        Service service = tomcat.getService();
        service.addConnector(getSslConnector());

        Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("/", root.getAbsolutePath());

        Wrapper defServlet = ctx.createWrapper();
        defServlet.setName("default");
        defServlet.setServletClass("org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet");
        defServlet.addInitParameter("debug", "0");
        defServlet.addInitParameter("listings", "false");
        defServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        ctx.addChild(defServlet);
        ctx.addServletMapping("/", "default");

        Wrapper jspServlet = ctx.createWrapper();
        jspServlet.setName("jsp");
        jspServlet.setServletClass("org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet");
        jspServlet.addInitParameter("fork", "false");
        jspServlet.addInitParameter("xpoweredBy", "false");
        jspServlet.setLoadOnStartup(2);
        ctx.addChild(jspServlet);
        ctx.addServletMapping("*.jsp", "jsp");
```

The problem is that i get this stacktrace during Tomcat startup

```
[01:07:15 INFO]: [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]] Marking servlet [jsp] as unavailable
[01:07:15 ERROR]: [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]] Servlet [jsp] in web application [/] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:545) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:526) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1044) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:985) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4875) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
```

And when i ask for a jsp i get this error `[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[jsp]] Servlet [jsp] is currently unavailable`

I worked with Tomcat in the past but to make web applications and it's the first time I use it in this way, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The following error should tell you exactly what is wrong:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet

You need to check that this class is on the class path of your embedded tomcat either because you specifically mentioned the jar or because it is in the lib folder.

Comment: I compile my program using Maven shade plugin without any relocation. The dependency is marked with the compile scope. I checked, the path is present in the output jar.

Comment: it needs to be runtime then, not compile